# nextjs server action/function fail to compile with babel in client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, async-await, babeljs

in a client component, calling an async server action/function defined in another module

```
export async function addTodo(data: FormData) {
  await fetch...
}
```

works fine with the default swc compiler.

but when I switch to babel by adding the .babelrc with the content

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"]
}
```

it failed to compile with the error

```
x Server actions must be async functions
    ,-[D:\Code\t\turbo1\apps\web\lib\sa.ts:77:1]
 77 |     return r.length;
 78 |   });
 79 | };
 80 | export function addTodo(_x4) {
    :                 ^^^^^^^
 81 |   return _addTodo.apply(this, arguments);
 82 | }
    `----
```

anything I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

we are using babel also !

```
{"presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],"plugins": ["transform-rebem-jsx"]}
```

Maybe you could post your error to next.js issue on [github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues), and i will upvote to make more attention

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Issue. In my case - the babel config (required by `jest` documentation) conflicted with `next.js`

So, instead using

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    ['@babel/preset-react', {runtime: 'automatic'}],
  ],
};
```

I've just deleted the file (entirely) and everything worked just fine. Worth mentioning that I've followed this [post](https://dev.to/ivadyhabimana/setup-jest-and-react-testing-library-in-a-react-project-a-step-by-step-guide-1mf0) in order to properly configure `jest`

Also worth mentioning: `jest` recommends to use the `create react app` in order to get everything up-and-running from day 0

> Setup with Create React App
>
> If you are new to React, we recommend using Create React App. It is
> ready to use and ships with Jest! You will only need to add
> react-test-renderer for rendering snapshots.